# how to pass a gameobject through a non static class in unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, object

I am making a game with Unity, and I am working on an inventory system, and what I am trying to do is create a class called Item which has all the necessary information and functions attached to create an item, and then it also has an object with it to use to create each item, this is the simple class so far

```
public class Item
{
  public Item(string name, GameObject obj)
  {
    //name to display in inventory
    String ItemName = name;
    //object to be shown in inventory slot
    GameObject ShownObj = obj;
  }
}
```

but when I try to use the object to create a new item, I pass through a unity game object and it gives me an error saying that you can't use a field initializer with a nonstatic class, how can I either fix this or get around it?
*here's how I tried using the class:*

```
Public gameobject item;
public Item testItem = new Item("test item", item);
```

Comment: Can you show the full script where you're trying to create your Item instance? I mean, the second part

Comment: I think it's the gameObject constructor, that you have to call using `new`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html

Comment: @KYL3R he is passing a public reference, if this code is inside a MonoBehaviour class this means that unity is creating those item object, when you call new on GameObject you will create an empty game object in runtime, and I doubt that this is what he wants

Comment: Also: 'p' in public should be lowercase, 'G' and 'O' in GameObject should be capitals. Probably a typo?

Comment: @Nefisto, ah yes - correct. So it's probably assigned via Inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call the `Item` constuctor outside of a function, when you pass in a non-static variable like your GameObject!

You are trying to declare & initialize the Item variable before at compiletime (because it's outside of a function), that's not possible for non-static stuff, because they can change.

But you can initialize it in `Start` which is called once. Just **declare** the reference as public variable and **initialize** it in `Start`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public Item item = new Item("test item", obj); // won't work!
    public GameObject obj;
    public Item item;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        item = new Item("test item", obj);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}

public class Item
{
    String ItemName;
    //object to be shown in inventory slot
    GameObject ShownObj;
    public Item(string name, GameObject obj)
    {
        //name to display in inventory
        ItemName = name;
        //object to be shown in inventory slot
        ShownObj = obj;
    }
}
```

Note: If your `Item` constructor only had a String as constructor parameter, it would work just fine, because the string is completely defined at compiletime.

Comment: You have created a field outside a class, this will not work, nor your obj, nor any of the items. What you can't do is to reference the obj, so what make this wrong isn't the constructor, is the reference to obj set in the constructor

Comment: @Nefisto, yeah, typed from memory. I just threw it into Unity and edited my post.

Comment: `You are trying to declare & initialize the Item variable before at compiletime (because it's outside of a function), that's not possible for non-static stuff, because they can change.` .. that's not entirely true this way .... the only thing you can not do is pass in the `item` reference since this one is non-static ;) It's also not created at compile time but in a quite interesting `c#` moment ... non-static fields are initialized in a static context right before the constructor is called ;)